# Can this question be made more narrow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging

I posted [the following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806173/non-trivial-i-know-what-number-youre-thinking-of) on math.stackexchange. Since I was asking for 'good examples' (and not just examples) I anticipated a "too broad" flag before posting. I therefore did my best to specify what kind of answers I was looking for and what I thought qualified as a good answer. Nevertheless, the question got flagged.

Since it wasn't immediately closed, I assume the community thinks it can still be improved. But how? Should I make it mathematically more rigorous what I'm looking for? Should I define what I mean by "non-trivial" more clearly, or why I would prefer some answers over others? I feel like overdoing this would be against the nature of the question. Or is the question just inherently too subjective for this site and should it be closed? But then what (SE) site does it fit on, as it's clearly about mathematics?

Comment: I guess this post on meta should be tagged ([meta-tag:specific-question]). The [tag-info](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info) says: "Please use this tag when you want to draw attention to a specific question on the main site. ... Do not use if your intention is to discuss/ask about a general issue, and you merely use questions as examples."

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I retagged.

Comment: Current status: question closed, but with 4 votes to reopen.

Comment: For future reference, it's perfectly acceptable to post a meta question first "I want to ask this, but I feel it's too broad. What can I do to focus it?" if you anticipate your question getting closed as too broad (or otherwise).

Comment: Status update: question re-opened.

Comment: That's good news, but how should I interpret this ? I didn't vote to reopen because I wanted to improve the question first. Does this mean the question was okay after all?

Comment: It means a few people thought the question sucked, and a few people thought the question was OK. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: **And** the first few people came before the next few people.

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't explicitly stating that you wanted "good examples" to your question, and you were getting just answers, then, most likely, your question was too broad. It would make sense to narrow the question down to what you actually want. Hope this helps!